# Problem in calculating the width of a padded div

Tags: javascript, css

Very basic question but I cannot find an answer.
Please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2sqx84j9/) fiddle.

Why does `getComputedStyle` fail to correctly calculate the width of the padded div? Isn't it supposed to include all paddings & margins in the computation

Thanks in advance!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <style>
    
     #A {
        display:inline-block;
        background:red; 
          padding-right:100px;
     }
    
    </style>
    
    <body> 
    
     <div id="A">a</div>              
     <div id="RESULT"></div>       
          
     <script>  
       document.getElementById("RESULT").innerHTML = "the width of A is:" + window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("A")).width;
     </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: I think it depends on the 'box-sizing' property, set it as border-box

Comment: The width of your element there _is_ about 7px, and it has 100px padding. If you _want_ to use a different calculation method, then you need to specify that, using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width does not include the padding if your `box-sizing` is set to `content-box`, which is the default. Therefore, it is not included in `getComputedStyle().width`. So you have two options:

1. Set `box-sizing` to `border-box` in your CSS, after which `getComputedStyle().width` will include the padding.
2. Access the padding of the element separately with `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("A")).getPropertyValue('padding-right')` and add it to the width.